# CIR and EIR - how to test/calculate?

Tags: network, monitoring

im wodering how to test CIR EIR between two localization? we have direct link between these locations and I got a question about CIR EIR

How can I test/calculate it?

Comment: Care to share more info on your setup? Is it feasible to have a PC/server at each location with `iperf` or a similar tool?

Comment: Yes we can do iPerf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `iperf` you can easily test CIR between locations.

Obviosly you need to use *adeqately sized machines* (enough CPU, correct ethernet interfaces size, etc.) for your link (**expecially if its a >1Gbps link**).

For realistic results, you should use an adequate packet size (depending on the MTU of your link) and leave it running for a couple of minutes saturating the link. This should give you a pretty close CIR measurement.

As for EIR, you can try with many `iperf` tests of short time (see the `-t` flag) with big payload (`-n` flag) and see if peak transfer rate differs enough from the mean rate calculated before.